# PHPMailer and Ionic with Gmail

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm attempting to create a contact form for my app using PHPMailer and Ionic with Gmail.
 The page receives (Failed.) result message when it triggers the script but I never get the email from the form. Here is my code:

template.html

```
   <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputEmail.$invalid && submitted }">
            <input ng-model="formData.inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email" required>
    </label>
  <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputSubject.$invalid && submitted }">
            <input ng-model="formData.inputSubject" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message" required>
    </label>
<label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputMessage.$invalid && submitted }">
            <textarea ng-model="formData.inputMessage" class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
    </label>
    <div class="padding">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="submitButtonDisabled">Send Message</button>
      </div>
  </form>
<p ng-class="result" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0;">{{ resultMessage }}</p>
```

app.js

```
 .controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.result = 'hidden'
        $scope.resultMessage;
        $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
        $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
        $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
            $scope.submitted = true;
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
            if (contactform.$valid) {
                $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'contact-form.php',
                    data    : $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
                }).success(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                        $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                        $scope.result='bg-success';
                    } else {
                        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                        $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                        $scope.result='bg-danger';
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed.';
                $scope.result='bg-danger';
            }
        }
    });
```

PHP

```
 <?php
    require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    if (isset($_POST['inputName']) && isset($_POST['inputEmail']) && isset($_POST['inputSubject']) && isset($_POST['inputMessage'])) {

        //check if any of the inputs are empty
        if (empty($_POST['inputName']) || empty($_POST['inputEmail']) || empty($_POST['inputSubject']) || empty($_POST['inputMessage'])) {
            $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit;
        }

        //create an instance of PHPMailer
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->From = $_POST['inputEmail'];
        $mail->FromName = $_POST['inputName'];
        $mail->AddAddress('my@emailaddress.com'); //recipient
        $mail->Subject = $_POST['inputSubject'];
        $mail->Body = "Name: " . $_POST['inputName'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['inputMessage']);

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "mygmailusername@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "passwordform";
        $mail->setFrom('mygmailusername@gmail.com', 'Contact Form');


        if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
            $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
        }

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
            echo json_encode($data);
            exit;
        }

        $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thanks! We have received your message.');
        echo json_encode($data);

    } else {

        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please fill out the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($data);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize $scope.formData = {} so that it can hold the values you are expecting. Right now, its trying to bind values to a scope variable that is undefined.

- Edit - It looks like you have no ng-click handler in your button to register the click to the submit. Please add this to your button. Additionally, $valid only works if your input values are enclosed in a .

template.html

```
<form name="myForm">
    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputEmail.$invalid && submitted }">
     <input ng-model="formData.inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Your Email" required>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputSubject.$invalid && submitted }">
      <input ng-model="formData.inputSubject" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Subject Message" required>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error': contactform.inputMessage.$invalid && submitted }">
      <textarea ng-model="formData.inputMessage" class="form-control" rows="4" id="inputMessage" name="inputMessage" placeholder="Your message..." required></textarea>
    </label>
    <div class="padding">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
              ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid || submitButtonDisabled == true"
              ng-click=submit(formData)>Send Message</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <p ng-class="result" style="padding: 15px; margin: 0;">{{ resultMessage }}</p>
```

What this is doing is its registering the $scope.submit the button, and in the HTML you're passing in formData as a parameter. The  now has a name and its required values are checked in ng-disabled of the button which refers to the same name and disables if the  I've cleaned up your app.js so that you're getting the params correctly.

```
.controller('ContactCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.result = 'hidden'
  $scope.resultMessage = '';
  $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
  $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
  $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted

  $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'contact-form.php',
      data    : $.param(contactform),  //param method from jQuery
      headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
    }).success(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
        $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
        $scope.result='bg-success';
      } else {
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
        $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
        $scope.result='bg-danger';
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I replaced  $scope.formData; with $scope.formData = {};... Still getting the Failed. message..  could it be a validation issue or the php code?